# Microsoft Bot Composer Send an HTTP request does not accept variable as Url input

Tags: httprequest, bots, bot-framework-composer

**Versions**

- Bot Composer version: 4.7.0-preview-191208-1

  - fresh project
  - yarn command triggered as in docs
- Latest Chrome and Edge (chromium) stable version on Windows 10 Pro

**Issue**

The 'Send an HTTP request' Url field no longer seems to accept a variable as input for me. For example:
`${getmyurl()}`

The validation seems OK:

[image: Send an Http request]

Where the getmyurl looks something like (it's not an escaping issue, I tried multiple values here with and without quotes etc...):

```
# getmyurl()
- just-a-test-string-to-see-if-this-throws-an-invalid-url-exception
```

The response in the 'Bot Framework Emulator' always gives the message:
`BuildQnaAnwserUrl does not have an evaluator, it's not a built-in function or a custom function.`

This used to work for me with an older version of the Composer (where the prefix was still an **@**). Is anyone else having this, is my syntax incorrect somehow?

Comment: `=settings.group.value` does seem to work so now I'm using that as a workaround. Not ideal but it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Url in a variable at start of conversation. eg. Set a property -> user.Url : urlString. In http method Url field -> Pass it as `${user.Url}`. The scope of variable can be defined as per requirement (user/conversation/dialog/turn)

[Send an HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJfk.png)